# Saving base64 string with Django

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library

I'm pretty new to django, so will be glad if somebody will point me in the right direction.

I have a base64 string.

I want to create image from it and save it on filesystem.

The problem is that I don't know how to correctly write path (in terms of Media_Url and other django constants).

Thank you.

Comment: Go for `media_url` because it is for uploaded images and documents stuff.. or may be generated programmatically like you generating images `static_url` for js, css, sprites, imgs

Comment: Can you supply a small example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://readthedocs.org/projects/django-imagekit/

I am using above mentioned package to create logo for uploaded image

So here is the code:

> In following lines I am creating thumbnail object using uploaded image, then

```
image_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, instance.image.path)
source_file = open(image_path)
image_generator = Thumbnail(source=source_file)
```

> And here I am checking in the database if there is any logo exists or not for the row and if not then create it.
>   for you I think `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` is more imp, and code is written in the model signal. (just for info)

```
if instance.is_logo:
    image_generator.setSizeParams(291, 167)
    result = image_generator.generate()
    new_image = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, instance.image.path.replace('.jpg','-logo.jpg'))
    dest = open(new_image, 'w')
    dest.write(result.read())
    dest.close()
```

I hope this ans will guide you in right direction..